# If the wave function of two identical fermions is antisymmetric, how can they be identical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fermions, pauli-exclusion-principle, identical-particles

If the wave function of a system of two identical fermions is antisymmetric, how can they be identical?
I replace two 'identical' particles and get a different system. This must mean they are not identical.
Why isn't this contradictory?

Comment: Does this (or any of the many similar previous questions) answer your question? [When are two fermions considered identical?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/322839/when-are-two-fermions-considered-identical)

Answer (score 2):

Since the wave function $\psi$ comes back to $-\psi$ under exchange of the particles, the probability *density* $\vert\psi\vert^2$ does not change and is thus independent of how you label the fermions.